# QBO3 XML to JSON converter

Tags: json, xml, type-conversion, qbo3

I would like to convert `XML` data to a `JSON` object within `QBO3`.

Is there a native method available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following in console:

`var xml = "<head><node1>node1</node1><node2>node2</node2></head>`"

`var xmlToJson = new XMLtoJSON;`

`xmlToJson.fromStr(xml);`

Note that in addition to the `fromStr[ing]` method, the XMLtoJSON object also has a `fromFile` method available.